# Pass value to User Control in windows Form

Tags: c#

I have a user control that needs value in Windows Form environment,

1. If I add my user control directly, I can see public variables in my user control.
2. If I add my user control programmatically, I can not see public variables in my user control.

Could any one help me with #2?

```
Code:
User Control :
public partial class uctest : UserControl
    {
        public DataTable dt1;
        public int ID;
               public ucTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     }
//////////////////////////////////////////////
Form :

public UserControl ucTest1  =new UC.ucTest();

Add User control into tapcontrol:
 tabTest.Controls.Add(this.ucTest1);

 string ID1 = ucTest1.ID; // here is the problem.
```

Comment: Why can't you see public variables?  Can you show code which demonstrates this problem?  You can pass values to an object by setting properties on that object, requiring the values in the constructor, etc.  It sounds like you tried to set a property and it didn't work, but we can't help you understand *why* it didn't work without seeing what you tried.

Comment: You need to show at least a little of code. I can't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have updated the question with some code, HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see public variables you have to create an object of that class first. If you don't want to create a new object then you can just add the static option to the public variable.

For example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string testVar = "I can see you!";

    public TestClass() {}
}

private class MyForm
{
    TestClass tc = new TestClass();
    MessageBox.Show(tc.testVar);
}
```

OR

You can use the static option on the public variable

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static string testVar = "I can see you!";

    public TestClass() {}
}

private class MyForm
{
    MessageBox.Show(TestClass.testVar);
}
```